# Making all floated children of a parent object the same height as the tallest child

Tags: html, css

This is what I have. It works alright but is not exactly the behavior I want.

```css
#container {
  height:250px; /*I want this to be set to auto*/ 
}             /*and have each child the height as the tallest.*/
#container > * {
  height:inherit;
  border-right: rgb(82,82,82) 2px solid;
  float:left;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.div1,.div2 {
  width: 8.66666%
}
.nav, .div3 {
  width: 41.66666% 
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
  <div class="div2"></div>    
  <div class="div3"></div>  
</div>
```

This works okay if I have set the height of the container, but when I go set it to auto or 100% the heights are not the same. When I go and mess with absolute positioning everything seems to collapse. Which is understandable. I have based my design on floats and variable widths. Does anyone have any suggestions or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Flexbox

The latest thing (8/16) but support is IE10+ (barely) and most Safari implementations (and some older versions of FF/Chrome) require vendor-prefixes.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > * {
  border-right: rgb(82, 82, 82) 2px solid;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 8.66666%;
  background: pink;
}
.nav,
.div3 {
  width: 41.66666%;
  background: orange;
}
nav {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS Tables

Has IE8 support but is slightly less *flexible* when wanting to adjust the layout for larger/smaller devices.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.container > * {
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: rgb(82, 82, 82) 2px solid;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 8.66666%;
  background: pink;
}
.nav,
.div3 {
  width: 41.66666%;
  background: orange;
}
nav {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```